# Invoking an XQuery Updating function results in the error If any subexpression is updating, then all must be updating

Tags: xquery, saxon, xquery-update

My XML document contains a record of the movement of an object. The XML document consists of a series of observations. Each observation contains the lat/long location of the object, the lat/long of the observing sensor, and a date/time stamp.

```
<Track-History>
    <Track-ID>XYZ</Track-ID>
    <Observation>
        <Target-Latitude>10.3</Target-Latitude>
        <Target-Longitude>20.8</Target-Longitude>
        <Observer-Latitude>40.0</Observer-Latitude>
        <Observer-Longitude>50.0</Observer-Longitude>
        <DateTime>20230202T071700.00</DateTime>
    </Observation>
    <Observation>
        <Target-Latitude>15.1</Target-Latitude>
        <Target-Longitude>25.2</Target-Longitude>
        <Observer-Latitude>40.0</Observer-Latitude>
        <Observer-Longitude>50.0</Observer-Longitude>
        <DateTime>20230202T071800.00</DateTime>
    </Observation>
</Track-History>
```

I want to fuzz the locations of the object by rounding the decimal lat and long values. So I created this updating function:

```
declare updating function f:fuzzPoint($lat as element(), $long as element())
{
    replace node $lat with 
        element {name($lat)} {round(number(data($lat)))},
    replace node $long with 
        element {name($long)} {round(number(data($long)))}
};
```

When I invoke that function:

```
{f:fuzzPoint($obs/Target-Latitude, $obs/Target-Longitude)}
```

I get this error message:

```
If any subexpression is updating, then all must be updating
```

Oxygen XML gives a red squiggly line under the function arguments, so apparently the arguments must be updating. Yes? If so, how to make the arguments updating?

Below is my complete XQuery Update program.

```
declare namespace f = "function";

declare variable $Track-History := doc('Track-History.xml');
declare variable $track-history-points := (for $i in $Track-History//Observation return [$i/Target-Latitude, $i/Target-Longitude]);
declare variable $AOR := (); (: should be a sequence of points, fake it for now :)

declare function f:isInside($points, $polygon) as xs:boolean
{
    true()
};

declare updating function f:fuzzPoint($lat as element(), $long as element())
{
    replace node $lat with 
        element {name($lat)} {round(number(data($lat)))},
    replace node $long with 
        element {name($long)} {round(number(data($long)))}
};

if (f:isInside($track-history-points, $AOR)) then
    for $obs in $Track-History//Observation return
      replace node $obs with
      <Observation>
            {f:fuzzPoint($obs/Target-Latitude, $obs/Target-Longitude)}
            {$obs/Observer-Latitude}
            {$obs/Observer-Longitude}
            {$obs/DateTime}
       </Observation>
else
   replace node $Track-History/* with
      <Track-History/>
```

Comment: I think you can't have something using XQuery update inside of the `with` clause of a `replace` update, there you are only allowed simple, non updating expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside an update expression – `replace node $obs with ...` – it’s not allowed to perform other updates. The code works if you modify `f:fuzzPoint` such that it returns the new element nodes:

```
declare function f:fuzzPoint($lat as element(), $long as element()) {
  element { name($lat) } { round(number(data($lat))) },
  element { name($long) } { round(number(data($long))) }
};
```

The `updating` keyword in the function declaration makes sense if you move the update operation inside the function body:

```
declare updating function f:replace($obs as element()) {
  let $lat := $obs/Target-Latitude
  let $long := $obs/Target-Longitude
  return replace node $obs with <Observation>{
    element { name($lat) } { round(number(data($lat))) },
    element { name($long) } { round(number(data($long))) },
    $obs/Observer-Latitude,
    $obs/Observer-Longitude,
    $obs/DateTime
  }</Observation>
};

if (f:isInside($track-history-points, $AOR)) then
  for $obs in $Track-History//Observation return f:replace($obs)
else
   replace node $Track-History/* with
      <Track-History/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Terrific explanation. Now my code is working!

Comment: Important lesson I learned from Christian: An XQuery Update program cannot have an update operation inside an update operation.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether

```
declare namespace f = "function";

declare variable $Track-History := doc('Track-History.xml');
declare variable $track-history-points := (for $i in $Track-History//Observation return [$i/Target-Latitude, $i/Target-Longitude]);
declare variable $AOR := (); (: should be a sequence of points, fake it for now :)

declare function f:isInside($points, $polygon) as xs:boolean
{
    true()
};

declare function f:fuzzValue($v as xs:double) as xs:double
{
  round($v)
};


if (f:isInside($track-history-points, $AOR)) then
    for $lv in $Track-History//Observation/(Target-Latitude, Target-Longitude) 
    return
      replace value of node $lv  
      with f:fuzzValue($lv)

else
   replace node $Track-History/* with
      <Track-History/>
```

is all you want to do there.

Comment: That's a good idea Martin. However, when I go to actually implement the fuzz function (what I showed is a too simplistic algorithm for fuzzing), fuzzing will require both lat and long values. That is, fuzzing latitude depends on longitude and vice versa.